# 'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: python, django, anaconda, virtual-environment

I have been using django commands in my virtual environment for a longtime....

suddenly today
When i run this command in my cmd from my Anaconda Env.....

**django manage.py runserver**

cmd responded with this

**'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

when i ran the command **"conda list"** it shows django package in the list...
do anyone know a solution to this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run it with python

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And make sure you have Django installed properly, and keep in mind you won't use anaconda for Django. Plus, if you're starting a project, the proper command will  be

```
django-admin startproject project_name
```

Call Django with `django-admin`. Not exactly intuitive, but this is how Django works.

Comment: yeah thats a typo in the question....i tried with python manage.py runserver.....it said import django something....then i uninstallled and reinstalled django package....everything worked fine then... :) thank you !! :)